# How to replace unity 7 with unity 8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, unity8

I really love the design of unity 8 and I want to run it on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit instead of unity 7. I have installed it with these command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

I logged out then chose unity 8 but I ended up with only a cursor. So I downloaded Ubuntu 15.04 from this website  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ following webupd8 tutorial but then I realized that it features unity 7. How can I get unity 8 running on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Unity 8 doesn't have a desktop yet and isn't supposed to be ready for normal use. However, if you really want it, then you should probably get the Ubuntu Desktop Next ISO rather than the normal Ubuntu Desktop ISO. You can get it from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next